# Interaction between (possibly) correlated variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, multicollinearity

Suppose I have a set of variables $a,b,c,d,f,g,h,i$, and I created a composite score by summing these eight variables into a composite score $\mathbf{e}=(a+b+c+d+f+g+h+i)$. Now I want to explore the interaction on y between e and another variable, z.

For example:
$$y = B1e + B2z + B3ez$$

I know variables a and b are all correlated with z. Under this case, and if the correlation between z and e is close to 0, is it appropriate to explore the interaction between z and e in a linear regression model?

Comment: Please explain a bit more what you mean by " I want to explore the interaction between e and another variable, z." The word "interaction" in statistics is usually specific to combinations of _predictor_ (aka "independent") variables in a regression or other model. It sounds, however, like you consider `z` to be a response or outcome variable and you want to see how well you can predict `z` from values of `e`. Please edit the question to clarify which you mean rather than posting a comment. Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: The correlations of $a$ and $b$ with $z$ do not imply $e$ will be correlated with $z.$  For instance (simplifying a bit), suppose $c=w-a-b$ where $w$ is uncorrelated with $z$ and $e=a+b+c.$  Moreover, appropriateness depends on your objectives and assumptions but regardless, it's always *mathematically* appropriate to explore an interaction. Moreover, the significance of an interaction in a model is generally unrelated to any correlation between the variables involved in the interaction.  Finally, what prevents you from analyzing the model you propose directly?